# three.js pick one of the geometry from obj file

Tags: three.js

i use objloader to load a obj file and add it into scene,

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( 'testcude.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
    if( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
        child.material = woodmap;
    }
});
object.name="stairs";
scene.add( object );
});
```

and i found that inside obj file, there is formatted like this:

```
#
# object Box002
#
v  -14.0000 17.9249 9.0000
v  -14.0000 17.9249 -9.0000
...
...
...
f 10/8/12 9/5/12 13/6/12 16/7/12
# 6 polygons
```

my question is, is that possible to pick the 'Box002' and set a rotation.x?
i try getObjectByName but no work..
i exported this obj file from 3dsmax, or any other file format possible to do this?
r66.

thank you, cheer~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply different operations to different parts of your model you need to save your model as separate objects from within 3dsmax. Wavefront .obj models are not named as you might think. What you are seeing is just a comment in the file and it is ignored when the file is parsed.

Comment: beside obj, or, or maybe any other import format are possible to do this? json? blender? collada? thank

Comment: yes these formats are supported by three.js, but you have to figure out which format is good for your needs.

Comment: hmmm, from what i have found & some suggestion from other, is that possible i can 'base on different material from mtl' to separate the object? i try first xD

Comment: hmm at the end i found that THREE.OBJMTLLoader() is the way to go. it support hierarchies in OBJ+mlt format, anyway thank you xD